# Is "captured my attention the most" a correct phrase to use?

Tags: grammar

> "The first part of this book consists of a brief history of ... and
>   the explanation of ..., *which captured my attention the most*."

Is there a way to emphasize how important that information was with different phrase?

Comment: You can simply change that clause to `, which <verbed> me.`, and use the a thesaurus to select the verb you like.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Why didn't I think of that?... Thank you!

Comment: "... which drew my attention the most."

Comment: I have another question. Is it better to use "consisted" or "consists"?

Answer (score 1):

"The first part of this book consists of a brief history of ... and the explanation of ..., [which was engrossing.](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/engross)

- If you're studying Shakespeare, you want the plays to engross you so you don't lose focus.